# when I use the split function in a for loop it creates a nested list, how do make It where it is only one list

Tags: python

I want to acsess the values in my list using indexes but I cant since its in a nested list
can someone please help where I can acsess  the values in my list properly with no errors

```
def get_info():
    infile = open('lol.txt','r')
    f = infile.readlines()
    id = input('enter your id:')
    new_list = []
    for line in f:
        if line.split(':')[0] == id:
            (line.strip())
            new_list.append(line.split(':'))
    print(new_list)
    print(new_list[1]) # error



get_info()
```

Output : [['1111', 'zoki', '2', '3', '1\n']]

Comment: `(line.strip())` on its own does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `extend()` function to add each item from the `split()` into the list.

Like this:

```
for line in f:
    if line.split(':')[0] == id:
        new_list.extend(line.split(':'))
```